# Outlook addin datepicker

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have a problem with datepicker in Outlook addin.

No matter which framework I use, JQuery, Boostrap etc.... I always get similar result as in picture.

Plain HTML datepicker works though but that's ugly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzxmm.jpg

I've tried shaping it with CSS but all widths are at 100% and even seen in debug but still it breaks the line at every few elements.

It should be 100% of width on that right side of screen where Outlook addin is.

Update:

[JQuery datepicker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mndnK.png)

Using JQuery datepicker result is the same. In head:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

And then in body:

```
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully add the jQuery date Picker. just followed this exact sample 
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

it must show up.  please share your HTML if you dont get this working. Also please indicate if this is a repro on Windows, Outlook Web Access? in what client you are observing this.
Fyi I was able to use it in Outlook Web Access see screenshot. So maybe you need to make a few changes in your HTML.  [image: I was able to add it successfully in OWA as well!]

Comment: I'm looking on Outlook Web access, currently I have collapsed bootstrap calendar in it. I will try adding jQuery calendar again when I get to it and show you the result, but  it was a same fail as with bootstrap last time I tried.

Comment: I included a screenshot if the JQuery date picker displaying correctly. (see updated answer)

Comment: Check the updated question, I've added image from jquery datepicker, result is the same. And the code. I copy pasted from their side, removed all CSS includes that could possibly interfer with it but still...

Comment: Never mind the previous comment I have figured out the problem. Problem was, for some reason it doesn't work inside table element. Looks like main MS css has to do something with it or something similar.... Anyway, trying the totally plain version from their site as you mentioned helped.

Comment: glad you were able to figure that one out!